# Issue with Safe Area - Fine on iPhone X, not on others

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x

So I'm trying to update my app for the iPhone X (a little late to the game, I know), and I enabled safe area, and fixed (supposedly) all my constraints to match. It looks perfect on the iPhone X. But for some reason, on all other iPhones, it still accounts for the iPhone X's notch, despite Safe Area correctly displaying where the UI should start and end. I'm at a loss. None of the constraints in question are hard coded, I set them all to the "standard" value (or so I believe).

[storyboard (first *button* is actually the talk bubble, which is just a static image, second is the paw print, which is an actual button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq72e.png)

[messed up iPhone 8 (bubble and ui elements should be at very top and bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/636Rs.png)

Here's my storyboard file: https://ufile.io/35zvs

UPDATE: [image for ercell0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwoIF.png)

Comment: Can you show pics?

Comment: @jack OP updated, thanks... let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Can you share `storyboard` or project(via dropbox link etc.) it's looks like you added too many constraints.

Comment: @jack storyboard file is on the link above. let me know if you need anything else. I didn't add any constraints-- only edited the ones autolayout made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using standard spacing for top and bottom for your `Banner View` with a required priority. try setting this to `superView: 0` or `safeArea: 0` and see if that corrects the issue for you.

[image: constraints for Banner View]

The updated view:

[image: constraints for Banner View after changes]

Comment: Hmm... if you meant make the priority 0 (which Xcode reset to 1) I just tried that, and it didn't seem to change anything. It's very possible I misunderstood what you wanted me to try.

Comment: Change `Second Item` to SuperView or SafeArea and set the `Constant` to 0.

Comment: @Branch I added a second image, closely review the differences, you dont need to change the priority.

Comment: Okay, so I did that. Worked perfectly got the top, bottom is still a little too high. It also got completely messed up on iPhone X.

Comment: @Branch did you set it to superview? try SafeArea.top /.bottom

Comment: I was using superview. I changed it to safearea (keeping constants at 0), and now, while it looks the same on iPhone X as it does 8 etc (thank goodness) all the UI elements are  a little too "in" the safe area... see OP for pic.

Comment: @Branch just add 8 or so to the `Constant`.

Comment: setting top to -20 and bottom to 20 did it. thank you sooo much! (it's telling me I have to wait 19 hrs to award bounty but I'll do it then)

Answer (score -1):

Can you change ViewAs from iPhoneX to iPhone8, and attach an image?
Other iphones your are testing on are running iOS11 or older?
If running older versions, safe-area won't be able to help with the alignment. For pre iOS11, use the constraints you were using previously or Layout Anchors.